# Daily bible verse from ourmanna.com API is not always displaying

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have HTML and JS code that should display the daily verse from ourmanna.com API. However, the verse is not always displaying. I was wondering if it's a problem on their side or my side?

here is the html code:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="daily-verse">
                <h2>Daily Verse</h2>
                <div class="body-daily-verse">
                    <div id="ourmanna-verse">Loading...</div>
                    <script src="https://www.ourmanna.com/verses/api/js/" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <p class="daily-verse-text">
                        
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <p class="verse-reference"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the script returned by ourmanna, you see the problem is a not escaped quote in the mannaverse:

```
var mannaverse='"'If you can'?" said Jesus. "Everything is possible for him who believes."';
```

Correct would be

```
var mannaverse='"\'If you can\'?" said Jesus. "Everything is possible for him who believes."';
```

So you cannot do anything about it, it is a ourmanna-problem.